# Как построить таблицу из массива numpy

Tags: массивы, pandas, numpy, table

подскажите пож-та как построить подобную таблицу имея массив numpy из следующего кода

```
textTopicsMtx=np.zeros(shape=(len(textCorpus),nTopics),dtype=float)
for k in range(len(textCorpus)): ## make the matrix of docs to topic vectors
    for tpcId,tpcProb in ldamodel.get_document_topics(textCorpus[k]):
        textTopicsMtx[k,tpcId]=tpcProb
```

вид таблицы
[image: таблица]

вид массива
[image: массив]

Comment: NumPy массив уже такая таблица. Что вы хотите? Цветную картинку? Как картинку? Как часть HTML страницы? Как часть PDF-документа?

Comment: хотелось бы вывести даже не цветную, а просто таблицу , в которой будут отображены все элементы, так как массив NumPy трудночитаемый

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r = np.random.rand(30, 30)
df = pd.DataFrame(r)
html = df.to_html()
print(html)
```

Использовать пример так:

> ```
> $ py temp.py > temp.html
> ```

Получится HTML таблица с данными.

**P.S.** Есть ещё [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). CSV данные можно загрузить в Excel и там с ними работать.

Comment: Спасибо, работает.